# How to move photos from Aperture to iphoto?

Tags: apple-aperture, iphoto

From time to time my daughter grabs my DS5100 and shoots. I import the results into Aperture along with the rest of the images. She does some tweaking sitting in front of my computer, and then wants to move the whole business into her iPhoto on her mac.

I tried 'export as library', then AirDropped the results to her, and then she tried to import them into iPhoto. I think that she just let it loose on all the files, with rather chaotic results.

Does iphoto have, in fact, some orderly way to absorb an Aperture library?

Comment: Are your system and your softwares up to date ? Aperture and iPhoto are now using the same libraries, so your issue should be solved :)

Comment: Two _different_ computers! The answer is fine beow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of, it is possible to open different Libraries with iPhoto, but you can not merge libraries (you need to use Aperture for that). The trick is to hold down the **Option** key as you start iPhoto, this will give you a small window where you can create a new library or open an existing library. This let you switch between iPhoto/Aperture libraries. More information over at [Apple's support pages](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2505).

If you do want to [merge libraries](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5296) you will have to use [Aperture (video)](http://support.apple.com/kb/VI159) for that. The idea is to switch to one of the two libraries you want to merge, then go to **File > Import > Library** and choose the second library.